# Ошибка в AndroidStudio на Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

При попытке сбилдить проект в `Android Studio` на `Ubuntu 14 32 bit`
получаю ошибку

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.common.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //RebbitMQ
    compile files('libs/commons-cli-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/rabbitmq-client.jar')
    //Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    //require gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    //required for support RxJava
    compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    //Picasso
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //Butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    //Dager 2
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4"
    //RxJava
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    retrolambdaConfig 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:+'
    //ORMLite
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.45'
    //Azure
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:1.2.0@aar'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае проблема была решена установкой `Ubuntu 64 bit` вместо `Ubuntu 32 bit`.

Answer (score 0):

Перейдите в раздел `File->Project Structure...` (или нажмите `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S`).

На левой боковой панели нажмите `Project` (в разделе `SDK Location`) и измените `Gradle version` (на что-то вроде `3.2`) и измените `Android Plugin Version` (что-то вроде `2.2.0` или `2.2.2`).

Это приведет к откату вашего AndroidStudio до версии `2.3`, чтобы вы могли продолжать развиваться до тех пор, пока Google не начнет исправлять все, что не так с `2.3`. Затем вы также можете изменить `buildToolsVersion` на `23.0.3`, чтобы избежать ошибку

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':app'

и ваш проект должен снова скомпилироваться.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625804/error-creating-a-project-on-android-studio-2-3

Comment: Я укже видил похожее решение, но если я делаю так, то приложение вобще не юилдится. Просто показывает строку проеграсса билда, но он не заканчивается, уже минут 20.

Comment: Вобщем, решил проблему установкой Ubuntu 64 bit вместо Ubuntu 32 bit. Не знаю почему, но это сработало!